# Connecting to Oracle with .NET app error: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: asp.net, oracle, database-connection

I am trying to Query a remote Oracle database from a Windows Server(production environment) through a .NET app.
I keep getting this exception. I have Oracle XE client installed on the system. I tried to install Oracle 64 bit connectors but the JVM won't allow me to do so.

`Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)`

I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: ASP.NET and JVM? What are you talking about?

Comment: This sounds like a serverfault question.

Answer (score 0):

Compile your .NET application as x86, and then try again.