# I cant use the class library reference in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, windows, vb.net, web-applications, oracle11g

I have a class library project which is used for Connect the database, the database is oracle, `oracle.dataaccess.dll` is used for connectiong the database. i need to use this class file in my web appication.But it throwing error like:

**"Could not load file or assembly `ClassLibrary1` or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: `System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary1' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`"**

But it is working fine in windows application all are in same solution only. all projects are using with 64-bit configuration only.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This question has been solved before:

[Connecting to Oracle with .NET app error: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702187/connecting-to-oracle-on-a-net-app-exception-system-badimageformatexception-an)

[Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209406/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-oracle-dataaccess)

[Deploying C# console app with Oracle.DataAccess reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851090/deploying-c-sharp-console-app-with-oracle-dataaccess-reference)

[Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' in 64 bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798802/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-oracle-dataaccess-in-64-bit-machine)