# Oracle.DataAccess.dll connectivity failed for web applications

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, dll, oracle11g

I am developing web application in asp.net, we are using Oracle 11g 64 bit server as back end, connecting through the following code fails to connect:

I am using Visual Studio 2012(4.5) under 64 bit compilation environment,

What I've tried :

I tried to connect oracle data access, dll which will perform Oracle db connectivity, it connects at windows applications, while trying with following code on web applications it fails:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client ' ODP.NET Oracle managed provider
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Types

Public Class RafiqClass
    Public Sub Intm()
        Try
            Dim oradb As String = "Password=valuesol;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=system;Data Source=orcle"
            Dim conn As New OracleConnection(oradb)
            conn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandText = "select department_name from departments where department_id = 10"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            dr.Read()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

I already added reference, library creation for this dll, but still it's not working with respect to web application

Whats error which occurs:

*Attempt to load oracle client libraries threw badimageformatexception. This problem will occur when running in 64 bit with the 32 bit oracle client components installed.*

Any guidance to solve this problem are welcome.

thanks in advance

Comment: So, the question is: do you have 32bit oracle client installed?

Comment: @Steve nope i preinstalled 64 bit server,i didnt installed 32 bit oracle client

Comment: Did you compile your application for AnyCPU as target platform?. If you try to switch to x86 target platform (if possible) those 32bit drivers should work.

Comment: @Steve yup i tried with anyCPU as target platform ,but it didnt worked,with respective x64 it was working fine in windows application not in web application

Comment: First time I tried connecting to Oracle from a web service, I had to give access to the user that IIS runs under (usually Network Service) to the Oracle folder on the HD. I tried for hours to find just the right folder and security setting but gave up and just gave it read/write access to the whole folder. Sorry I cannot find the exact link anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry can't comment so I m posting as answer. your ODP.Net libraries are 32 bit and the web apps will required 64-bit to work on. On windows environment you can run 64bit as well as 32bit apps on a 64 bit environment , but in an IIS you must need same environment libraries to work.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Answer (score 2):

As stated on another SO Post (by Y. Ecarri):

This question has been solved before:

[Connecting to Oracle with .NET app error: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702187/connecting-to-oracle-on-a-net-app-exception-system-badimageformatexception-an)

[Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209406/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-oracle-dataaccess)

[Deploying C# console app with Oracle.DataAccess reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851090/deploying-c-sharp-console-app-with-oracle-dataaccess-reference)

[Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' in 64 bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798802/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-oracle-dataaccess-in-64-bit-machine)